# Embed Video on Facebook Page with OG

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

Recently our videos started to no longer embed on Facebook Pages. Facebook still recognizes the link, shows a thumbnail but doesn't play the video inline. The weird thing is that it still works on a Facebook Wall, just not on a Facebook Page.

This is the page I try to post:
http://zentr.cc/AHRReN

I use this set of OG-tags:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="148322691992629">
<meta property="og:title" content="How To Make An Interactive Video">
<meta property="og:description" content="">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ducf06ut3d7t7.cloudfront.net/AHRReN/hqthumb">
<meta property="og:type" content="video">
<meta property="og:video" content="http://d2ma12218neagj.cloudfront.net/player.impl.swf?AHRReN">
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://d2ma12218neagj.cloudfront.net/player.impl.swf?AHRReN">
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<meta property="og:video:width" content="1920">
<meta property="og:video:height" content="1080">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Zentrick">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://zentr.cc/AHRReN">
```

The Facebook Debugger tells everything is fine:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fzentr.cc%2FAHRReN

Is someone experiencing similar issues or found a solution?
YouTube, Vimeo and Yahoo links are still working, but I can't find what we are doing differently.

Comment: Please go search their bug tracker for current bugs matching your problem before asking. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/598397860207749

Comment: Thanks for the response! I searched everywhere but missed that one.